# Retrieve email using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using app login access token retrieved through following API -

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=client_credentials

Can I retrieve email address (primary email not the facebook email) of any user if it is public using Graph API?

Thanks
Lakhan

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to get users primary email:

1. For the authenticating user (ie the one who has granted your application access to their profile) and only when you explicitly request that permission.
2. If the email is explicitly made public by some arbitrary user not authenticating with your app, then that will be available to you also. Any publically visable info you can see via facebook.com is equally accessible via the API.

For getting the authenticating users email, when you first request the oAuth dialog you need to pass a `scope` with the `email` permission (as well as whatever other permissions you require). See more about permissions [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) and more about using scope [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) .

When the email is available it can be found in the `User` payload, see more about the API request and payload [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc here : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

With the email argument, you will be able to get the email.