# Facebook Javascript SDK Login response object does not return user email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to create an app in my website to sign people up to a newsletter, getting their email address after they log in using the facebook log in button.

After a user logs in, the response object in the console does not show the email address, despite I asked for that permission and despite according to Facebook's documentation, that piece of data is accessible by default. Other public data such as their name shows though.

The application lies in the website, not on Facebook. The website does not have an SSL certificate. Documentation does not say that an SSL certificate is required to access the user's email.

I've done all tests logging in with an email address, not a phone number.

I need the email address in order to submit the newsletter to subscribers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve email using Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710282/retrieve-email-using-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

Having the permission to access the user's email address does not guarantee that there actually is a valid email address for that user.

You could also signup for Facebook with a phone number in which case they don't have a valid email address for that user or it is deemed invalid for other reasons.

You should handle that case gracefully and simply ask the user for his email address in case Facebook does not return one.