# Retrieve public email from user with Graph API 2.5

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My question is related to "[Retrieve email using Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710282/retrieve-email-using-graph-api)" and to the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user. I would like to get some clarification about the retrieval of PUBLIC user info espacially email address and gender. That's why I am asking again.

My scenario:
We use SAP CRM Interaction Center to answer comments/messages on our company facebook page. Therefore we created a Facebook APP with Page Access Token to manage our page using Facebook API. We are able to retrieve and to reply to comments/messages without entering the Facebook page directly. Everything is working fine. So I assume that the APP, Page Access Token, calls to the API etc. are correct.

My understanding is that if a user writes a comment on our page the user does not grant any permission to retrieve his/her email address. Furthermore the comment itself as well as the user is not related to our APP (User does not use the APP).

What I tried:
I did some tests in the Graph API Explorer to retrieve PUBLIC user info. I entered our Page Access Token and tried the following:

`post-> /v2.5/{user_id}?fields=name,link,email,gender`

The result contains the ID, Name, and Link but not the email address and not the gender.
The `user_id` belongs to a test user with PUBLIC email address, gender etc. I retrieved the `user_id` from a test comment on our page.

`post-> /v2.5/{comment_id}?fields=from`

I also tried with my own Facebook User but the result is the same.

My Question(s):
Is it generally possible with Graph API 2.5. to retrieve the email address of the user who wrote a comment on our page if the email address is PUBLIC to everyone? If yes, how can I retrieve it?

Did I make a mistake in my Graph API Explorer example?

Any help and clarification is welcome. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Best,
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn’t matter if the email address is public on Facebook – the user still has to grant your app permission to read it.
**There is no way to get the email of a user that is not even using your app.**

(And `gender` needs `public_profile` permission.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast and clear answer. Maybe I was naive. I mean I can still go to the page of the user who wrote the comment and if his/her email is public I can copy/paste it. That's why I thought that it should/might be possible to retrieve the email with the Graph API for this particular user.